# Can't create blank form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I don't know what's wrong with my environment, since I copied the application back to my local laptop, it's never working smooth, as now, I can't create the blank form, the whole app will crush if I just click the create blank form button?

Anybody has the similar experience ?

thanks

My Envrionment: MS access 2007 + ODBC SQL server 2005

App initial build on ms-access 2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced that type of behavior in Access 2003, but not yet with 2007.

In those cases I launch the database with the /decompile flag on the end, recompile my VBA code, and exit.  Upon return, I've never failed to be back in control of a functional database.

I usually keep a 'Decompile' shortcut in my project folder.  Here's the shortcut target:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\MSACCESS.EXE" "I:\Development\MyDatabase.mdb"  /decompile
```

Comment: Be sure to make a backup before doing this, though to be honest, I've never lost a single line of code from decompiling. Of course, I compile my code so often that it's almost impossible for the compiled p-code to get out of synch with the canonical VBA code.

Comment: I did once have a problem with the MDB after doing a decompile.   Like you though I always made a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If decompiling doesn't work then try importing all the objects into a new MDB.

We also recommend occasional decompiling.  For example if it hasn'tbeen done for quite a while startup times can increase substantially.

[Decompile or how to reduce Microsoft Access MDB/MDE size and decrease start-up times](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm)